# Split column into multiple columns based on content of column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

I have a column with data like this

Ticket NO: 123456789 ; Location ID:ABC123; Type:Network;

Ticket No. 132123456, Location ID:ABC444; Type:App

Tickt#222256789 ; Location ID:AMC121; Type:Network;

I am trying like this

```
new = data["Description"].str.split(";", n = 1, expand = True)
data["Ticket"]= new[0]
data["Location"]= new[1]  
data["Type"]= new[2]

# Dropping old  columns
data.drop(columns =["Description"], inplace = True)
```

I can separate based on ";" but how to do for both ";" and "," ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general solution, that allows you to perform as much processing as you like comfortably. Let's start by defining an example dataframe for easy debugging:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Description': [
    'Ticket NO: 123456789 , Location ID:ABC123; Type:Network;',
    'Ticket NO: 123456789 ; Location ID:ABC123; Type:Network;']})
```

Then, let's define our processing function, where you can do anything you like:

```
def process(row):
    parts = re.split(r'[,;]', row)
    return pd.Series({'Ticket': parts[0], 'Location': parts[1], 'Type': parts[2]})
```

In addition to splitting by `,;` and then separating into the 3 sections, you can add code that will strip whitespace characters, remove whatever is on the left of the colons etc. For example, try:

```
def process(row):
    parts = re.split(r'[,;]', row)
    data = {}
    for part in parts:
        for field in ['Ticket', 'Location', 'Type']:
            if field.lower() in part.lower():
                data[field] = part.split(':')[1].strip()
    return pd.Series(data)
```

Finally, apply to get the result:

```
df['Description'].apply(process)
```

This is much more readable and easily maintainable than doing everything in a single regex, especially as you might end up needing additional processing.

The output of this application will look like this:

[image: Partial Output]

To add this output to the original dataframe, simply run:

```
df[['Ticket', 'Location', 'Type']] = df['Description'].apply(process)
```

[image: Full Output]

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
new = data["Description"].str.split("[;,]", n = 2, expand = True)
new.columns = ['Ticket', 'Location', 'Type']
```

Output:

```
>>> new
                  Ticket             Location            Type
0  Ticket NO: 123456789    Location ID:ABC123   Type:Network;
1   Ticket No. 132123456   Location ID:ABC444        Type:App
2       Tickt#222256789    Location ID:AMC121   Type:Network;
```

The `[;,]` regex matches either a `;` or a `,` char, and `n=2` sets max split to two times.

Another regex `Series.str.extract` solution:

```py
new[['Ticket', 'Location', 'Type']] = data['Description'].str.extract(r"(?i)Ticke?t\D*(\d+)\W*Location ID\W*(\w+)\W*Type:(\w+)")
>>> new
      Ticket Location     Type
0  123456789   ABC123  Network
1  132123456   ABC444      App
2  222256789   AMC121  Network
>>>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o60KQn/1). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive flag
- `Ticke?t` - `Ticket` with an optional `e`
- `\D*` - zero or more non-digit chars
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
- `Location ID` - a string
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
- `(\w+)`-  Group 2: one or more word chars
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
- `Type:` - a string
- `(\w+)`-  Group 3: one or more word chars

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One approach using `str.extract`

**Ex:**

```
df[['Ticket', 'Location', 'Type']] = df['Description'].str.extract(r"[Ticket\sNO:.#](\d+).*ID:([A-Z0-9]+).*Type:([A-Za-z]+)", flags=re.I)
print(df[['Ticket', 'Location', 'Type']])
```

**Output:**

```
      Ticket Location     Type
0  123456789   ABC123  Network
1  132123456   ABC444      App
2  222256789   AMC121  Network
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!